# Configure and use third part Apps for SharePoint 2013 in dev environment without DNS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SP 2013 dev env

h t tp  spitlab  .I want to configure app store in this environment

will I be able to do it without access to a DNS server

I followed the below two articles

http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Develop-SharePoint-2013-Napa-App-In-Local-Dev-Environment-Configuring-On-Premises-without-DNS.aspx

I am able to install third party apps but when I click on it . it gets redirected to sfs.in

next i try this

http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com/2013/07/shortcut-to-prepare-sharepoint-2013-app.html

same thing I am able to install 3rd party apps but when i click on it .. it goes to intranet.com

so is it possible to install third party apps on a dev box without DNS and check out third party apps and if what steps am i missing ?